# Laravel Unit Testing, how to "seeInDatabase" soft deleted row?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5

I'm working on a small unit test where I soft delete a row. To mark the test as successful I have to find that row with:

- a given ID and
- `deleted_at` column **should not be** null.

I can fulfil first condition - because obviously I know the ID.

Unfortunately I don't know how to tell `seeInDatabase` method that I expect `deleted_at` **not to be** null:

```
$this->seeInDatabase(
       'diary_note_categories',
       [
           'id' => 'a7e35ad0-6f00-4f88-b953-f498797042fc',
           'deleted_at' => null // should be is not null, like <> or != or whatever
       ]
 );
```

Any hints?

`'deleted_at <>' => null` *breaks*

`'deleted_at' => ['!=' => null]` *breaks as well*

Comment: This has been solved by writing custom method `seeIsSoftDeletedInDatabase`.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you solved this? You could create your own answer.

Comment: @mniess, check Espadav8's answer. We work together and he provided correct solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not currently possible. Both `seeInDatabase` and `notSeeInDatabase` just pass the array directly to the `where` method of the query builder and that doesn't understand how to deal with anything other than `=` when passed an array.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2b4b3e3084d3c467f8dfaf7ce5a6dc466068b47d/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L452

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    // If the column is an array, we will assume it is an array of key-value pairs
    // and can add them each as a where clause. We will maintain the boolean we
    // received when the method was called and pass it into the nested where.
    if (is_array($column)) {
        return $this->whereNested(function ($query) use ($column) {
            foreach ($column as $key => $value) {
                $query->where($key, '=', $value);
            }
        }, $boolean);
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Option 1 - Add the following code to your TestCase class which you extend your test cases from

Gist: https://gist.github.com/EspadaV8/73c9b311eee96b8e8a03

```
<?php
/**
 * Assert that a given where condition does not matches a soft deleted record
 *
 * @param  string $table
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  string $connection
 * @return $this
 */
protected function seeIsNotSoftDeletedInDatabase($table, array $data, $connection = null)
{
    $database = $this->app->make('db');

    $connection = $connection ?: $database->getDefaultConnection();

    $count = $database->connection($connection)
        ->table($table)
        ->where($data)
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->count();

    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $count, sprintf(
        'Found unexpected records in database table [%s] that matched attributes [%s].', $table, json_encode($data)
    ));

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Assert that a given where condition matches a soft deleted record
 *
 * @param  string $table
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  string $connection
 * @return $this
 */
protected function seeIsSoftDeletedInDatabase($table, array $data, $connection = null)
{
    $database = $this->app->make('db');

    $connection = $connection ?: $database->getDefaultConnection();

    $count = $database->connection($connection)
        ->table($table)
        ->where($data)
        ->whereNotNull('deleted_at')
        ->count();

    $this->assertGreaterThan(0, $count, sprintf(
        'Found unexpected records in database table [%s] that matched attributes [%s].', $table, json_encode($data)
    ));

    return $this;
}
```

### Option 2 - Install the following composer package

This composer package is the exact same code as above, but packaged up for Composer.

`composer require kirkbater/soft-deletes`

Then use it inside of your specific test class:

```
<?php

use Kirkbater\Testing\SoftDeletes;

class MyTestClass extends TestClass {

    use SoftDeletes;

}
```

Comment: Have you added this as a pull request yet @EspadaV8 ?

Comment: @NateRitter No, I have not. I don't think it would be accepted.

Comment: Actually, checking the repo there is this PR - https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/11887 - and Taylor didn't want to merge it in.

Comment: That's a bummer @EspadaV8 .  I threw a question out to Taylor there as to why it wouldn't be included, but whatever. I'm just adding it to my TestCase for now. Great addition. Thanks for doing that, even if Taylor doesn't see fit to use it.

Answer (score 38):

I did it in this way:

```
$this->seeInDatabase('diary_note...',['id' => 'a7e35ad0'])
->notSeeInDatabase('diary_note...',['id' => 'a7e35ad0','deleted_at'=>null]);
```

So I'm checking in two steps

1. I check if there is a record with our id in the table
2. I check if there is no record with our id and deleted_at = null in the table

Answer (score 15):

This is an old question, but for those using more recent versions of Laravel (5.4 and above), there is now an `assertSoftDeleted` assertion: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#available-assertions).

So the answer to the original question would now be:

```
$this->assertSoftDeleted('diary_note_categories', [
    'id' => 'a7e35ad0-6f00-4f88-b953-f498797042fc'
]);
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this doesn't work anymore. Latest Laravel 9 uses model instance on assertSoftDeleted() and it can't be used with arrays. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#assert-deleted

Answer (score 6):

Assert the given record has been deleted (Laravel 5.4 and above).

**assertSoftDeleted**(string|Model $table, array $data = [], string|null $connection = null)

Example with id:

```
$this->assertSoftDeleted('table_name', ['id'='value'])
```

Example with model:

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
$user->delete();
$this->assertSoftDeleted($user);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used in Laravel 6

```
$this->assertDatabaseMissing('stores', [
'id' => $test_data['store']->id, 'deleted_at' => null
]);

$this->assertDatabaseHas('stores', ['id' => $id]);
```

Answer (score -2):

It is not tested, but try like this :

```
$this->seeInDatabase(
       'diary_note_categories',
       [
           'id' => 'a7e35ad0-6f00-4f88-b953-f498797042fc',
           'deleted_at' => ['deleted_at' ,'!=', null ] // should be is not null, like <> or != or whatever
       ]
 );
```

Comment: Hi, are you guessing or are you sure? `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[HY105]: Invalid parameter type: 7  (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "diary_note_categories" where ("id" = a7e35ad0-6f00-4f88-b953-f498797042fc and "deleted_at" = deleted_at)) `

Comment: I can't find documentaton for this function, but you can test if this is working in 5 minutes. Besause this way is used in eloquent queries.

Comment: I did and it's not working. Check Espadav8's answer for the proper solution. Cheers.